# Forwarding a block as a property in a class inside a class

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, block

I have 3 viewController classes: vA, vB and vC.

I have a method on vA like:

```
- (void) showMessage:(NSString *)message withTitle:(NSString *)title {
 ...  bla bla
}
```

I am self.navigationController pushing vB. I want vB to run this method from vA, so what I did was to create a property in vB like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) void (^showMessage)(NSString *message, NSString *title);
```

and when I create vB inside vA and just before pushing it,  I do this:

```
vB.showMessage = ^(NSString *message, NSString *title){
        [myself showMessage:message withTitle:title];
};
```

and I can call showMessage block from vB.

My problem is this: I want to forward this same method to vC that is a third viewController I will be pushing from vB. So this is vC, running a method from vA:

```
vA pushing vB pushing vC
```

Is there a simpler way to forward that to vC or do I have to repeat the whole thing of creating another equal property on vC and again wrapping the method in a block. If this is true as it is already a block I will have to do this:

```
vC.showMessage = ^(NSString *message, NSString *title){
        self.showMessage(message, title);
};
```

right?

I would like to continue using this block stuff. I am in love with it.

I know I can use notifications, delegates, etc., but this block new stuff is simpler and makes code tight.

Comment: You can just assign `vC.showMessage = self.showMessage;` What was the issue you are facing with that? and then call vc.showMessagae(message, title); or when you are in vc, just use self.showMessage(message, title);

Comment: Make sure you copy blocks instead of only using a strong property, btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just assign `vC.showMessage = self.showMessage;` before pushing to `vC`. Then call `vC.showMessagae(message, title);` or when you are in `vC`, just use `self.showMessage(message, title);`

Try it like this,

in `vA.h` file,

Add,

```
typedef void (^ShowMessageBlock)(NSString *message, NSString *title);
```

Then import `vA.h` file in `vB.h` file and declare,

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) ShowMessageBlock showMessage;
```

Do the same declaration in `vC.h` file as well.

After that when you are pushing to `vB`,

```
vB.showMessage = ^(NSString *message, NSString *title){
        [myself showMessage:message withTitle:title];
};
```

and when you are pushing to `vC`,

```
vC.showMessage = self.showMessage;
```

Then you can use it as `self.showMessage(@"", @"");` in both classes.